# Add variable content to a new column in file

Tags: bash, awk, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I don't have much experience using UNIX and I wonder how to do this:

I have a bash variable with this content:

```
82 195 9 53
```

Current file looks like:

```
A
B
C
D
```

I want to add a new column to a file with that numbers, like this:

```
A 82
B 195
C 9
D 53
```

Hope you can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what happens if you have more lines in the file than you have values in your variable? what happens if you have more values in your variable than there are lines in the file? what is the delimiter (space? tab?) in the final result? do the columns need to line up as displayed in your sample output (ie, fixed width)?

Comment: @Barmar I always try before asking, but in this case I don't know how to do it :(

Comment: @markp-fuso **A1**: that's not happening, it's the same number always. **A2**: that's not happening, it's the same number always. **A3**: Delimiter is space **A4**: no, just need the new values in a new column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or simply use paste with a space as the delimiter, e.g. with your example file content in `file`:

```
var="82 195 9 53"
paste -d ' ' file <(printf "%s\n" $var)
```

(**note:** `$var` is use *unquoted* in the process-substitution with `printf`)

**Result**

```
A 82
B 195
C 9
D 53
```

Note for a general POSIX shell solution, you would simply pipe the output of `printf` to `paste` instead of using the bash-only process substitution, e.g.

```
printf "%s\n" $var | paste -d ' ' file -
```

Answer (score 1):

With `bash` and an array:

```
numbers="82 195 9 53"
array=($numbers)
declare -i c=0         # declare with integer flag

while read -r line; do
  echo "$line ${array[$c]}"
  c=c+1
done < file
```

Output:

```
A 82
B 195
C 9
D 53
```

Comment: `c=c+1` should be `((c=c+1))` or `let c=c+1`

Comment: @Barmar: `c=c+1` is here fine, too.

Comment: Oh, it does it because of `declare -i`. Nice.

Answer (score 1):

One idea using `awk`:

```
x='82 195 9 53'

awk -v x="${x}" 'BEGIN { split(x,arr) } { print $0,arr[FNR] }' file.txt
```

Where:

- `-v x="${x}"` - pass OS variable `"${x}"` is as `awk` variable `x`
- `split(x,arr)` - split `awk` variable `x` into array `arr[]` (default delimiter is space); this will give us `arr[1]=82`, `arr[2]=195`, `arr[3]=9` and `arr[4]=53`

This generates:

```
A 82
B 195
C 9
D 53
```

---

---

The question has been tagged with `windows-subsystem-for-linux`.

If the input file has Windows/DOS line endings (`\r\n`) the proposed `awk` solution may generate incorrect results, eg:

```
 82       # each line
 195      # appears
 9        # to begin
 53       # with a space
```

In this scenario OP has a couple options:

- before calling `awk` run `dos2unix file.txt` to convert to unix line engines (`\n`) or ...
- change the `awk/BEGIN` block to `BEGIN { RS="\r\n"; split(x,arr) }`

Answer (score 0):

With `mapfile` aka `readarray` which is a bash4+ feature.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

##: The variable with numbers
variable='82 195 9 53'

##: Save the the variable into an array named numbers
mapfile -t numbers <<< "${variable// /$'\n'}"

##: Save the content of the file into an array named file_content
mapfile -t file_content < file.txt

##: Loop through the indices of both the arrays and print them side-by-side
for i in "${!file_content[@]}"; do
  printf '%s %d\n' "${file_content[i]}" "${numbers[i]}"
done
```